# Maximum String length for Javascript (text to be copied into HTML element) [Javascript, HTML]

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-length, marquee

I hope someone knows this, since I didn't find a direct answer when searching Google or here...

What is the maximum length I can put into a Javascript string, intended to be copied into a HTML marquee element?

This is an example for my case (taken from my script) :

> document.getElementById("song2").textContent = npt + "  \u266B  " + npt + "  \u266B  " + npt;}

I have the above snipped in my javascript and the 'npt' part is dynamically changing text that (as part of the script) is taken from a text file via the fetch API.
At the moment I have that string repeated for ~200 and was wondering how many times more I can repeat it before the string is too long for javascript to be recognized.

Also, I know about the marquee tag being deprecated (no lecture please), but in my case it's the only solution that works to my satisfaction and the in the way I intend (except for the flicker at first scroll in) and by repeating the text string, I want to achieve the feel of an endless scrolling text without gaps.

Thanks for all help

Comment: [google first result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) - but I doubt you actually want an element with 9 quadrillion length (you probably don't have enough RAM for that)

Comment: @JaromandaX - to be fair, from that link they clarify that Firefox limits the max string length to a little over a billion length, which would only allow one to capture around 300 copies of the St. James Bible.

Comment: @JaromandaX and Alexander Nied, thanks for both your answers! With those numbers I could actually understand and get what I was looking for. Currently the max length of my text string has ~150 characters (letters) at most and I repeated it into the javascript command around 650 times. So in total the string that gets put into the marquee HTML is around 97500 characters (Letters, numbers or symbols) and therefore should be well within a safe zone to not crash a browser displaying the HTML. In fact it seems I could even increase the string at this point, if needed.

Comment: why would you repeat it 650 times - surely you can code it better :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Sadly, I can't code it better :/ (Someone smarter might could) I know almost nothing about coding and basically build the HTML with what I copied/pasted from Google searches (lots of them over the past 8 weeks). Simply said, it's a single page HTML to accompany a music live stream and it displays the "Now Playing" data. At times the song title is to long to be shown in a single line and I have javascript put it into the marquee then. But I also don't want the gaps between each scroll, so I duplicated the string to create a gapless marquee, even if displayed for a long time